# MAUI project giving platform version error

Tags: maui, maui-blazor, maui-community-toolkit, maui-windows, .net-maui.shell

I just updated my visual studio to the latest version, then I am getting "platform version is not present for one or more target framework" error. I didn't do anything to the project or to the pc or to the visual studio other than the update.
The resources available in the internet about Maui is very less because it's a new framework, so I'm stuck in this error. Any useful answers will be appreciated.

I tried to build and rebuild the solution, uninstall and install the visual studio and dotnet 6 sdk.
And also made sure that the maui framework is installed using visual studio installer.[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsJDc.jpg)]

Comment: 1. Can you try to execute the command `dotnet workload install maui-ios` under `C:\Windows\System32>`, see this [working example](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15021#issuecomment-1746830452). 2. According to the error log, you can also refer to the official link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/troubleshooting?view=net-maui-8.0#platform-version-isnt-present

Answer (score 0):

For your information, [.NET 6 is out of support for MAUI](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/maui) since 8th May 2023.

Can you give a try to the following commands and see if it solves your problem?

1. First, manually [download .NET 8 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0)
2. Then run the following command to install maui

> dotnet workload install maui

3. Then run the following command to install workloads for iOS & Android

> dotnet workload install maui-android maui-ios